# Device Chooser shows physical phone, but not GalaxyTab

Tags: android, eclipse, usb, device

I've been working with a small 2.2 API 8 phone (Samsung i5500) physically connected to PC with Eclipse without problem. Now I have access to a GalaxyTab 10.1 P7500 3.1 API 12 too, but Eclipse only finds my old phone and not the GalaxyTab. I have made identical settings on the Tab as on the Phone: Applications - Development and select USB debugging. I've tried both connected and one at a time. I've restarted Eclipse. Is there something more I need to do?

If I change project Build Target Level to 12, still only the API-level 8 phone shows up.

The GalaxyTab doesn't give me a KIES prompt when I connect the USB, but the phone does. However, the tab says itself that USB debugging is activated and Windows reacts when I connect its USB. But the Android Device Chooser in Eclipse knows nothing about it.

The GalaxyTabs battery does not charge when it is connected to my PC by USB, but the phones battery does charge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might need to download the corresponding driver for the Galaxy Tab. I had to do this when I tried connecting my Galaxy Nexus.

http://androiddrivers.net/category/samsung-android-drivers/

Comment: THanks, but that made no difference for me. Your link was broken but I found GT-P7510_USB_Driver_v1_3_2360_0-escape.exe under androidforums.com and I isntaleld the p7510 KIES from Samsung.com and upgraded it. But same problem remains.